# How to use SFTP in a script to non-interactively pull file from remote host?

Tags: shell-script, scp, sftp

I want to use a shell script to pull a file from another server. I have written a script where i can do this but i want the script to work non-interactively so that it doesn't prompt me for the password and works automatically if i hard-code the same and let the script have what it needs.

I have done this before for `FTP` however, in out new servers the `FTP` connections are blocked and we can use only `SCP` or `SFTP`. My earlier script was something like this which used to work with `FTP` and did the job well without asking for the password:

```
#!/bin/bash -vx
ftp -in 100.XXX.XXX.XX<<END_SCRIPT
quote USER username
quote PASS password
bin
prompt off
cd /directory/in/remote/host
lcd /directory/in/local/machine
mget *
bye
END_SCRIPT
```

I tried the similar for `SFTP` in a script and it works for Interactive mode but like `FTP` i am not able to use the non-interactive options for `SFTP`. Following is my code to fetch particular files from the remote machine:

```
#!/bin/bash -vx

path="/tmp/testanks"

sftp username@100.XXX.XX.XXX <<EOT
cd $path
get Bharti*
quit
EOT
```

How can i change the above code in a way that i could provide this script the username and password to make it non-interactive.

I understand that providing a hard-coded password is a security concern but right now i am concerned more about fetching the files immediately. I would really appreciate if i could get the secured ways of doing it as well along with the answer i desire.

Answer (score 10):

With [curl](https://curl.haxx.se/):

```
curl sftp://example.com/file.zip -u user:password
```

Note that for that [public-key Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7260/1391963) is preferred to using a password:

`curl sftp://example.com/file.zip -u user`

This will attempt to use `~/.ssh/id_rsa` as a private key. You can specify another one with `--key`.

Answer (score 7):

the solution is to use `scp`, you add local's public key to the end of remote authorized_keys file.

then

```
 scp username@100.X.X.X:Bharthi/* $path
```

on local host, look in `.ssh` dir, if you don't have any .pub, do the following first (and only one time)

```
ssh-keygen (1)
scp-copy-id username@100.X.X.X (2)
```

1. accept all default, DO NOT enter a passwd when prompt
2. enter password for username @ 100.X.X.X

Comment: +1 as a side note `scp` has issues on multiple big files or huge number of small files, in which case you could use `rsync`, however you'll need `rsync` on both machines where `scp` only needs to be on machine running the script.

Comment: It seems like the server can block `scp` and enforces `sftp`. I tried to use `scp` and got this message: *This service allows sftp connections only.*. I remember, that this may be due to a chrooted environment which only works with sftp, not scp. (To be confirmed).

Comment: My server won't let me use scp. is there a solution for using only the sftp client?

Comment: SFTP does not require shell login, scp and rsync do. Keep this in mind.

Comment: If you're SFTP host has disabled non-interactive access (rendering scp useless), you can get around this by sending the commands from standard input as answered in [another question here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/105791/62742).