# upload to sftp batch mode

Tags: sftp

I need to upload files to an SFTP server as part of an automated pipeline process (so **can not** be interactive). I do not have ssh access so I **can not** use scp or rsync.

I have had some success using the [solution proposed in this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/105791/30276):

```
sftp user@server <<EOF
put localPath remotePath
EOF
```

However I am looking for something a bit more solid, as I will have no indication if this fails. For example, if I wanted to download from an SFTP server I can use the following syntax:

```
sftp user@server:remotePath localPath
```

Is there an equivalent one-liner for uploading?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use "Batch Mode" of sftp.
From manual:

```
> -b batchfile
>              Batch mode reads a series of commands from an input batchfile instead of stdin.  Since it lacks user interaction it
>              should be used in conjunction with non-interactive authentication.  A batchfile of ‘-’ may be used to indicate
>              standard input.  sftp will abort if any of the following commands fail: get, put, reget, reput, rename, ln, rm,
>              mkdir, chdir, ls, lchdir, chmod, chown, chgrp, lpwd, df, symlink, and lmkdir.  Termination on error can be sup‐
>              pressed on a command by command basis by prefixing the command with a ‘-’ character (for example, -rm /tmp/blah*).
```

Which means, you create a temporary file with the commands and execute the commands in the file with "sftp -b tempfile user@server"

There are other tools around for such things, e.g. lftp

Answer (score 5):

The [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/441262/30276) by [Marco](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/140875/marco) led me to create a simple script to wrap the process, but essentially what I am doing in the script is the following:

1. creating a batchfile with `put {local} {remote}` commands for the file(s) to upload.
2. running the following command:

`sftp -b {batch_file} -i {identity_file} -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no {username}@{hostname}`

This command will work without needing any input from the user, and will have an error code that can be checked for success or failure.

I just wanted to include this answer here in a more complete form for future visitors.